# gtk2hs: Unable to render combo box on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, gtk2hs

My problem is very confusing to me because it occurs only on Windows (I am testing with XP). It all works perfectly on Linux.

I am using gtkbuilder to load my layout. (in case it's important)

```
route_input <- builderGetObject builder castToComboBox "route"
comboBoxSetModelText route_input
comboBoxAppendText route_input "first"
comboBoxAppendText route_input "second"
comboBoxAppendText route_input "third"
t <- listStoreToList =<< comboBoxGetModelText route_input
putStrLn $ show t
```

Prints:

```
["first","second","third"]
```

In the window, it displays a combo box with three entries, all of them blank
I hit the "ok" button, which runs the following code in its signal handler:

```
t <- listStoreToList =<< comboBoxGetModelText cbox
putStrLn $ show t
selection <- comboBoxGetActiveText cbox
putStrLn $ show selection
```

Prints:

```
["first","second","third"]
Nothing
```

Does anyone have any ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that it was a package version issue. The gtk package in the Windows version was one version number higher than the version on the Linux machines. That must have broken something.